# Idiom to hide `self` in Objective C blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, self, weak-references

When I have an Objective C instance create a block that needs to refer to the instance, I frequently do so through a weak pointer that won't keep the instance alive and produce a retain cycle, like this:

```
__weak MyType *const weakSelf = self;
void (^aBlock)() = ^(){
  // Do things with weakSelf instead of self.
}
```

I'd like to have an idiom that prevents me from making use of the strong self in the block. Ideally, when using the idiom, I'd get a compile error if I try to use `self` in the block instead of `weakSelf`. A run time error would also be okay.

Comment: you can get a warning for that.. would that help?

Comment: Latest versions of Xcode + ARC will detect strong reference cycles in blocks and give you a warning.

Comment: The warning is helpful, thanks. I've got a solution that I'll post. It's not perfect, but it might provoke a better solution.

Comment: Can the compiler warnings be turned in to errors?

Comment: Of course. You should _always_ turn all compiler warnings to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution for this that I don't especially like, but it might provoke a better answer. I'll leave this unanswered in the hope of a better solution arriving.

Here's one way to do it:

```
// Here's a method definition…
-(void) aMethod
{
  // Want to create a block in which its impossible to refer to strong "self".
  // Begin a new scope to do this in.
  {
    // Within this scope, cover the existing "self" with a weak variant.
    __weak STWeatherTableViewController const *weakSelf = self;
    __weak STWeatherTableViewController const *self = weakSelf;

    // Sadly it's _not_ possible to simply do:
    //   __weak STWeatherTableViewController const *self = self;
    // … it gives a warning about initialisation of a variable form its own
    // uninitialised value, which makes sense, though you might hope the
    // compiler would work out what's going on.

    // Make a block that captures the covered self and does something with it.
    void (^exampleBlock)() = ^(){ [self lineHeight]; };
    exampleBlock();
  }

  // Now, back in the scope of the original method, "self" is non weak
  // again.
  [self doSomething];
}
```

I guess, if you really cared a lot about this, you could use a macro. It would at least abstract the idea and make uses easy to find and notice in code:

```
#define WEAKEN_SELF(classType) \
__weak classType const *weakSelf = self; \
__weak classType const *self = weakSelf
```

Or even:

```
#define WEAKEN_SELF(classType) \
__weak classType const *weakSelfTemporary##__LINE__ = self; __weak classType const *self = weakSelfTemporary##__LINE__;
```

Which you'd use it like this:

```
-(void) testMethod
{
  // You still need that scope or you cover the original "self".
  {
    WEAKEN_SELF(STWeatherTableViewController)
    void (^exampleBlock)() = ^(){ [self someMethodOrOther]; };
    exampleBlock();
  }
}
```

I'm unconvinced it is worth the effort though. Having the compiler warnings is probably good enough and they can presumably be turned in to errors?